# lose state between mutations and getters - Vuex/ Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, getter

I try to render components based on the state of the button clicked (`navBar.vue`).

I see the actions and mutations with the correct data but I cannot get the getters to retrieve the state of `pageVisible` (should be either `perso-page` or `result-page`).
It is either:

- undefined
- nothing at all (no console.log)

I have tried many options like setting some `async await` but nothing was really successful. I am sure it is an obvious thing but I cannot pinpoint the reason why.

Please let me know if you see how I could get the correct state in the getters and call it on `page.vue` (for now it will not render anything but this is not the main point of this question).

Thank you!

*page.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="container-week">
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <InputPerso v-if="pageVisible === 'perso-page'"></InputPerso>
    <Results v-else></Results>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from '../components/week-seven/NavBar'
import InputPerso from '../components/week-seven/personalised/InputPerso'
import Results from '../components/week-seven/Results'

export default {
  name: 'Week7',
  components: {
    NavBar,
    InputPerso,
    Results
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pageVisible: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getCurrentPage() {
      return this.$store.getters.currentPage
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*navBar.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="container__links">
      <li>
        <button @click="setContentPage('perso-page')">
          Personalised
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button @click="setContentPage('result-page')">See result</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavBar',
  data() {
    return {
      pageVisible: 'perso-page'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setContentPage(page) {
      this.$store.dispatch('pageDisplayed', page)
    }
  }
}
```

*index.js (store)*

```
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'
import getters from './getters'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

new Vuex.Store({
  state: () => ({
    pageVisible: 'perso-page'
  }),
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,

})
```

*actions.js*

```
export const pageDisplayed = (context, payload) => {
  context.commit('PAGE_DISPLAYED', payload)
}
```

*mutations.js*

```
export const PAGE_DISPLAYED = (state, payload) => {
state.pageVisible = payload
}
```

*getters.js*

```
export const currentPage = (state, payload) => {
return state.pageVisible
}
```

Comment: are you using named modules?